# Regular expression always returning false in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following Javascript to check that a filename includes only letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores.

```
var patt = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/;
if (!patt.test(filename)) {
    alert("Filename contains invalid characters");
}
```

Firefox works fine, filenames containing spaces are rejected and the others allowed, but in IE and Chrome, it always returns FALSE, regardless of the filename being passed to it.

I also tried using the RexgExp object:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/);
```

but the result is the same.

Comment: Why this dot inside the square brackets?

Comment: if you want the extension (ie .jpg) you need to use "\." not "." . is the regex wildcard, matches all characters (including spaces)

Modified Regex: ^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+$

if you also take @EvertonAgner 's post into consideration, the regex is
^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*$

Comment: I have to ask... Are you sure the filename that you're passing isn't an empty string (on chrome and IE)? I mean, the `+` modifier demands that there should be at least 1 character.

Comment: @SGrimminck every character is taken literally inside the `[ ]` brackets, so `\.` isn't necessary.

Comment: @EvertonAgner Ah I forgot about that thanks.

Comment: Careful, @EvertonAgner . . . not **every** character is taken literally inside brackets . . . for example, it's a good think that that hyphen is the last character in the group.

Comment: Yes, good point. The `[` and `]` chars souls be escaped as well if needed.

Comment: In JS, the "special characters" within brackets are: closing brackets `]`, backslashes `\ `, carets `^`, and hyphens `-`.  More info here, if interested:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a hint from @EvertonAgner, I checked the filename that is being passed, and Chrome and IE are adding "C:\fakepath\" to it. So I need to strip that off before checking it.

This is the code that now appears to be working:

```
var filename = filename.split("\\").pop();
var patt = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/;
if (!patt.test(filename)) {
    alert("Filename contains invalid characters");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your regex, I'd check if the `filename` that you're testing isn't an empty string.

Since your regex is using the `+` modifier, it demands that your input must have at least one character.